# How to retrieve an URL from the route using @Param

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am writing an image processor proxy, similar to [imageproxy](https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy), but using NestJS.

I want to declare an endpoint like this: `GET /api/trim/http://your.image.url` where `http://your.image.url` is the URL of the image that I want to transform.

In my controller, I would do something like this:

```
@Get('trim/:imageUrl')
  async trimCanvas(
    @Param('imageUrl') imageUrl: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    console.log(imageUrl);
    return 'OK';
  }
```

However, if I make a request, the controller is never hit and, instead, I get a default 404. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

By default, slashes will not be captured by the url param. You can append a regex in parentheses to your [route param](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) to change this behavior. Add a wildcard `*` to your param, so that it also accepts `/`:

```
@Get('trim/:imageUrl(*)')
```

Try it out in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n00owq948m?fontsize=14&initialpath=%2Ftrim%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.local&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts).

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not work due to: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(*)/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: Strange, it works for me. What express version are you using?

Comment: You can try a running example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n00owq948m?fontsize=14&initialpath=%2Ftrim%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.local&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts

Comment: Nope, couldn't make it work, and I do not understand why... at the end, given the resource relations I ended up changing the design of my API though, so I was able to achieve the same with query parameters...